# Unable to delete and update JSON string C#

Tags: c#, json, winforms

I am creating an application that asks the user the put data. The data is then stored to a structured JSON file. So far the user can enter as many data as they can, and I can display the values of the JSON on a textboxes if they decided to see old data.
I need to give the user the ability to **Delete** and **Update** the data when required.
Below is how the JSON strings look like. [Click here to see the application interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XatP5.png)

```
[
  {
    "Record": 1,
    "IPaddress": "168.147.8.343",
    "Machinename": "taurus",
    "username": "root",
    "password": "root",
    "sourcefolder": ".../.../.../...",
    "destfolder": ".../.../.../...",
    "filextension": "db",
    "removedownloaded": 0
  },
  {
    "Record": 2,
    "IPaddress": "178.255.255.1",
    "Machinename": "sami",
    "username": "sami",
    "password": "sami",
    "sourcefolder": "././././.",
    "destfolder": "././././.",
    "filextension": "json",
    "removedownloaded": 0
  },
  {
    "Record": 3,
    "IPaddress": "255.255.255.255",
    "Machinename": "root",
    "username": "taurus",
    "password": "taurus",
    "sourcefolder": "............/............./",
    "destfolder": "............/............./",
    "filextension": "txt",
    "removedownloaded": 0
  },
  {
    "Record": 4,
    "IPaddress": "168.147.8.343",
    "Machinename": "taurus",
    "username": "root",
    "password": "root",
    "sourcefolder": ".../.../.../...",
    "destfolder": ".../.../.../...",
    "filextension": "db",
    "removedownloaded": 0
  },
  {
    "Record": 5,
    "IPaddress": "168.147.8.343",
    "Machinename": "taurus",
    "username": "root",
    "password": "root",
    "sourcefolder": ".../.../.../...",
    "destfolder": ".../.../.../...",
    "filextension": "db",
    "removedownloaded": 0
  },
  {
    "Record": 6,
    "IPaddress": "168.147.8.343",
    "Machinename": "taurus",
    "username": "root",
    "password": "root",
    "sourcefolder": ".../.../.../...",
    "destfolder": ".../.../.../...",
    "filextension": "db",
    "removedownloaded": 0
  }
]
```

This is what I did to allow the user to create a new JSON file every time they enter a new data.

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to Add", "ADD", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.Yes)
    {

        filePath = @"C:\Users\Sami\Desktop\Companies\Nautitech Mining Systems Pty Ltd\Code\JSON\app-db.json";
        // Update json data string
        //jsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(DataloggerList);
        //System.IO.File.WriteAllText(filePath, jsonData);
        string text = File.ReadAllText(filePath);

        var currentList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Datalogger>>(text);

        //Create new Datalogger

        Datalogger myself = new Datalogger

        {

            Record = ++count,
            IPaddress = textBox2.Text,
            Machinename = textBox8.Text,
            username = textBox4.Text,
            password = textBox3.Text,
            sourcefolder = textBox7.Text,
            destfolder = textBox6.Text,
            filextension = textBox5.Text,

        };

        if (currentList != null && currentList.Any())
        {
            var lastRecordNumner = currentList.OrderBy(q => q.Record).Last().Record;
            myself.Record = lastRecordNumner + 1;

        }
        else
        {
            currentList = new List<Datalogger>();
        }

        currentList.Add(myself);


        string output = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(currentList, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
        Console.WriteLine(output);
        File.WriteAllText(filePath, output);
    }
    else
    {
        this.Activate();
    }


}
```

When the user click on **First**, **Last**, **Forward** and **Backward** the data will be displayed on the textbox and I need to user to update and save the data when needed. I have tried this but I didn't work:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to Save", "SAVE", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        Datalogger myself = new Datalogger
        {
            Record = ++count,
            IPaddress = textBox2.Text,
            Machinename = textBox8.Text,
            username = textBox4.Text,
            password = textBox3.Text,
            sourcefolder = textBox7.Text,
            destfolder = textBox6.Text,
            filextension = textBox5.Text,

        };
        filePath = @"C:\Users\Sami\Desktop\Companies\Nautitech Mining Systems Pty Ltd\Code\JSON\app-db.json";
        // Serialize it.

        string serializedJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myself);
        // Print on the screen.  
        Console.WriteLine(serializedJson);
        string output = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myself, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);

        File.WriteAllText(filePath, output);
    }
    else
    {
        this.Activate();
    }

}
```

Any Thoughts?

Comment: What exactly does not work? The updating or the saving? Also, are you saving all records in one Json file or individual files?

Comment: You need to add/update or delete the data to the `List<DataLogger>` that you load initially, then you should serialize the list not a single element built from your textboxes. Of course, you need to identify the elements in your list. It seems that the Record field could be used as key to search the records to update or delete

Comment: @estebro sorry for the confusion, Save is same as update. When I type update I am referring to Save in the application interface. I am saving all the data in one JSON file

Comment: @Steve When I use this currentList = new List<Datalogger>(); currentList.Remove(myself); The whole JSON is deleted. I need to user to decide which record need to be updated or deleted

Comment: Keep the list global (at the form class). When you want to update (or delete) a particular record read back the record value and search the list for the element to update (or the element to remove) then serialize the list and save. Of course you shouldn't allow your user to change the Record value because this is your key to find the element to update/delete

Comment: @Steve Thanks, I will try it and see if it works

Comment: @Steve could you please provide an example of what you described?

Answer (score 0):

As an example of the above comments:

Note that for this to work you need to set the textbox for the Record field to the value of the Record from the DataLogger class *everytime* you change the data displayed by your textboxes - Do not try to calculate this by yourself, always use the value present in the DataLogger instance. When you add an element always calculate the next value using the Count method from the List global instance

First, be sure to have a class level variable to hold your list

```
public class FormForDataLogger : Form
{
     private List<DataLogger> currentData = null;

     // also keep this in one place (but is better if you read it from the config file
     private string filePath = @"C:\Users\Sami\Desktop\Companies\Nautitech Mining Systems Pty Ltd\Code\JSON\app-db.json";

     .....
```

Now in the Form constructor load this data from the file

```
 public FormForDataLogger()
 {
    if(File.Exists(filePath))
    {
        string text = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
        currentData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Datalogger>>(text);
    }
    else
        currentData = new List<DataLogger>();
 }
```

Now when you want to add data

```
 private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    Datalogger myself = new Datalogger
    {
        Record = currentData.Count + 1;
        IPaddress = textBox2.Text,
        Machinename = textBox8.Text,
        username = textBox4.Text,
        password = textBox3.Text,
        sourcefolder = textBox7.Text,
        destfolder = textBox6.Text,
        filextension = textBox5.Text,
    };
    currentData.Add(myself);

    string output = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(currentData, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
    File.WriteAllText(filePath, output);
}
```

when you want to update data

```
 private void btnModify_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     int record = Convert.ToInt32(txtRecord.Text);
     DataLogger logger = currentData.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Record == record);
     if(logger != null)
     {
         // update logger with your textboxes data
         logger.IPaddress = textBox2.Text;
         logger.Machinename = textBox8.Text;
         logger.username = textBox4.Text;
         logger.password = textBox3.Text;
         logger.sourcefolder = textBox7.Text;
         logger.destfolder = textBox6.Text;
         logger.filextension = textBox5.Text;

         // Save everything
         string output = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(currentData, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
         File.WriteAllText(filePath, output);

     }
}
```

Delete is similar

when you want to update data

```
 private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     int record = Convert.ToInt32(txtRecord.Text);
     DataLogger logger = currentData.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Record == record);
     if(logger != null)
     {
         currentData.Remove(logger);
         // Save everything
         string output = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(currentData, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
         File.WriteAllText(filePath, output);

     }
```

Comment: thanks for you answer, I appreciate that a lot. It worked for add and delete and that solved half of my problem again many thanks for that, but never worked for update? It just keep the list same and nothing changes!!

Comment: DId you update the variable _logger_ in the btnModify_Click with the values from your textboxes?

Comment: is this why we have DataLogger and Datalogger, one is the original and one to update it?

Comment: Ahh okay now I have seen the logger variable, it wasn't there earlier, but I am getting error in Convert.ToInt32(txtRecord.Text). this is the error "System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.'" Any idea on what causing this to happen

Comment: I figure this one out, Record should always have a value, otherwise, if it is blank it won't be in the right format, but now I have this error "System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: source'" generated by this line "DataLogger logger = currentData.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Record == record);"?

Comment: As I have told you, everytime you set the textboxes with the values to be changed by your user you should set the value for the Record textbox with the value from the currently selected DataLogger instance. In case of new record you should set this value using currentData.Count + 1 (If you leave it blank then the Convert.ToInt32 cannot work).